# Change ionic title dynamically when user want

Tags: ionic-framework

I need to change for "`my items`", User should be able to change "`title`"

I already try

`<ion-input type="text" (ngModel)="Item.title"></ion-input>`

> Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this.

```
<ion-input type=“text” [(ngModel)]=“Item.title”></ion-input>
```

Comment: Great..  You just forgot [(ngModel)].